# In gradle is there a way to determine if it is being run by eclipse during the configure phase?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

It seems eclipse can't handle some things that gradle from the command line and intellij cover.

I would like to put in code in gradle that will execute during the configure phase only when it is being run from eclipse.

Something like the below in the root build.gradle

```
if(we are being executed by eclipse) {

     task prepareForEclipse {
         // do something necessary for eclipse
     }
     // add a dependency of the above to this:
     firstTaskExecutedWhenEclipseDoesAnImportOrReImport {
         dependsOn prepareForEclipseImport
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildship-3-1-is-now-available/31600 Otherwise, show an example and tell what you exactly mean be _configure phase_.

Comment: Maybe I'm sort of thinking added to item above:

Comment: Could you please explain why `eclipse.synchronizationTasks` cannot be used for this?

Comment: I just tested this.  It does not execute the task before the configuration or during the confuguration pass but after the subprojects have been configured.

Comment: The issue is with command line gradle and with other ides we can build the project after a git clone.   But with eclipse, eclipse somehow manages dependencies for it's build differently than gradle does so we have to run gradle compile once outside eclipse before eclipse imports the project structure from gradle, because some generated source code is not built before eclipse compiles even thought the compileJava task in gradle has the generated source code as a dependency.  So now we have to run the generation step manually before an eclipse import, it woudl be nice not to have to do this.

Comment: Keep in mind that Eclipse compiles incrementally for performance reasons. Running the Gradle build from the beginning up to the compile phase every time when saving a file would be super slow. If possible, do the code generation in a separate project that is used as dependency (that would be the clean solution and not Eclipse specific). Otherwise, when the code is generated based on project files that can be change, do the code is generation in `eclipse.autoBuildTasks`. But touch project files if and only if the have to be changed to avoid an infinitive build loop.

Comment: Instead of running the generation step manually, you can run it automatically in `eclipse.synchronizationTasks` (only this step plus adding the result to the Java build path). In contrast to `eclipse.autoBuildTasks`, `eclipse.synchronizationTasks` will not run when a project file is changed, only after importing the project or when changing the Gradle build file.

Comment: @howlger sounds useful - would this work if lets say a directory of java source files was missing and it was created and filled in a task set as a dependency of synchronizationTasks ? I will eventually test this. My issue is eclipse would compile with it's own dependency engine instead of executing gradle to build the class files and it seems not to recognize the source files when added by the gradle task, even though gradle itself when running it gets the dependencies correct.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse uses its own compiler to incrementally compile Java files on save. Via `eclipse.synchronizationTasks` you can generate code and add the generated code, e.g. as a source folder or as a JAR, to the Eclipse's Java build path, so that Eclipse sees the generated code. When you run a full Gradle build from inside Eclipse, it does not fail, right? If this does not answer your question, please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks - Yes, from the command line or with intellij everything works fine.  I will try this at some point.  If this was an answer I would vote for it :)